# Variable substitution in Log4J for multiple instances of same webapp

Tags: log4j, tomcat7, virtualhost

I have one webapp that I deploy multiple times on Tomcat (version 7) separated by host. The webapp uses Log4J for logging and I'd like use variable substitution for log path, e.g.

```
log4j.appender.file.File=${webapp_log_dir}/logfile.log
```

I cannot find other ways to perform this variable substitution than through `System.setProperty("webapp_log_dir", "some path")`, but this is not useful, as there is only one system, hence this system-wide variable will be overwritten on every new deployment of the webapp.

How can I define a property replacement that has a more narrow scope, so it will be app-local / host-local? Do I need to use another logging mechanism that Log4J?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Log4j 1.x you can only use Java System Properties (which are global) for interpolation.

Log4j 2.x offers a much larger set of property sources: cf. [Log4j 2 Lookups](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#lookups). The [Web Lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#web-lookup) is probably what you are looking for.

It's also easy to write your own lookup (cf. my [`log4j-tomcat`](https://github.com/copernik-eu/log4j-plugins)) for example.

**BTW**: Log4j 1.x is unsupported since 2015 and has several known vulnerabilities. Tomcat 7.x reached end-of-life in 2021.

Comment: Hi Piotr, thank you for your reply. I have updated to Logback and utilizes the PropertyDefiner interface to set property values dynamically in the config file. Thank you for your heads up on the EOL of Tomcat 7, but I'm currently locked to using this version.